# Trying to insert JSON data into a datatable widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, datatables

I have a Java Web Project where I have a GET endpoint that I am hitting to retrieve JSON data. Firebug shows I am getting the JSON data in the form

```
[{"id":7,"serial":"7bc530","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":8,"serial":"4a18d27","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":9,"serial":"f30ef","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":10,"serial":"9e6d","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":11,"serial":"4d8665a3","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null},
{"id":12,"serial":"4fe1457","randomDouble":0.0,"randomDouble2":0.0,"randomDouble3":0.0,"date":1352228474000,"removed":null}]
```

On the HTML side I have this,

```
<table id="table_id">
   <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>serial</th>
      <th>randomDouble</th>
      <th>randomDouble2</th>
      <th>randomDouble3</th>
      <th>date</th>
      <th>removed</th>
      </tr>
</thead>
 <tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Here is what I have on the javascript side, I found another post from someone on here with this format that worked for them.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var Table = $("#table_id").dataTable({
       "bFilter":false,
       "bPaginate":false,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bServerSide":true,
       "bInfo":false,
       "sAjaxSource": ApiUrl(),
       "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback){
           $.ajax({
            "dataType": 'json',
               "type": "GET",
               "url": sSource,
               "data": aoData,
               "success": fnCallback
           }); 
       }
    });
```

The table is displaying the columns, but it isn't pulling in the data. As I said, I did verify that the JSON data is getting sent to the webpage through Firebug -- through the GET request this is making.

I find datatables to be extremely confusing and I can't get this JSON to actually populate...

Any assistance would be very appreciated.

Edit:

I tried this,

```
var Table = $("#table_id").dataTable({
       "bFilter":false,
       "bPaginate":false,
       "bProcessing": true,
       "bServerSide":true,
       "bInfo":false,
       "sAjaxSource": ApiUrl(),
       "sAjaxDataProp": ""
    });
```

Comment: you can use "sAjaxSource": to point it to some servlet/php that will send the json data...

Comment: The issue with that is that DataTables expects an object with an array called "aaData" with the data source. I can't modify the JSON coming in.

Comment: Than look for a way to wrap and set it into aaData and pass it to datables constructor as a "text file" source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for server side:

```
 var Table = $("#table_id").dataTable({
   "bFilter":false,
   "bPaginate":false,
   "bProcessing": true,
   "bServerSide":true,
   "bInfo":false,
    "aoColumns": [
    { "mData": "id" },
    { "mData": "serial" },
    { "mData": "randomDouble" },
    { "mData": "randomDouble2" },
    { "mData": "randomDouble3" },
    { "mData": "date" },
    { "mData": "removed" }

    ],
   "sAjaxSource": "url",
   "fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
    $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
        map = {}
        map["aaData"] = json
        fnCallback(map)
    } );
}
});
```

UPDATE regarding last comment:

```
"fnServerData": function ( sSource, aoData, fnCallback ) {
  $.getJSON( sSource, aoData, function (json) { 
        $.getJSON('second_json_url', function(secondjson) {
            $.each(secondjson, function(index, object) {
              json[index].serial = secondjson[index].name
            })
            map = {}
            map["aaData"] = json
            fnCallback(map)
        })
  });
}
```

Comment: I may go this route. There is something I want to do and I think I can do it with your implementation. The json I'm passing back (what I have above) includes the element "serial". I have another array that has a element name "serial" and that array has an element "name". I need to figure out how to bring in "name" from the other array and replace it where serial is in this one. Thoughts?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to load first json and replace values from serial column to values from new json ?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely what I would like to do if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can read from an arbitrary data source. Check out the documentation below (found [here](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/custom_data_property.html)). This works for server-side processing and ajax data sources.

> Additionally, it is possible to set sAjaxDataProp to be an empty
>   string, which results in DataTables treating the given data source as
>   the table data array (rather than as property of an object).

Comment: I just tried that and it isn't populating the data. Firebug console has a "TypeError: aData is undefined" in Jquery.dataTables.js =/

Comment: You will not be able to use bServerSide unless you implement the server side protocol http://datatables.net/usage/server-side. Are you trying to implement paging/sorting/filtering?

Comment: I'm not. I removed bServerSide and that error went away. I get a new one unfortunately. A popup window pops up and says "DataTables warning (table id = 'table_id'): Requested unknown parameter '0' from the data source for row 0"